# Create 3D array of matrix to integral powers (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a 3x3 matrix that I want to compute several integral powers of and wanted to use a vectorized solution in Matlab rather than for-loops.

Since the output will be a list of matrices, it will have to be a 3D matrix.

Here's the exact question: Given a 3x3 matrix M, how can I create a 3D matrix such that the i-th page will be M^i?

I've tried bsxfun() shenanigans with power(a,b) and mpower(M,b) but can't find the right way to do it. When I try -1.^[1:10] I get the correct result [-1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1] so now I just need to find how to do this with a matrix.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are we talking about `M^k` or `M.^k`? (`M` being the matrix and `k` the integer exponent)

Comment: I am looking for M^k, when I try things like bsxfun() with mpower() rather than power() it says "Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix." I would love any answer you have that works :)